# How to use Workbox setDefaultHandler

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I'm switching from sw-toolbox to Workbox and I can't figure out how to use [setDefaultHandler()](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing.Router).

If I try (as stated in the documentation linked above):

```
workboxSW.router.setDefaultHandler({
    handler: new workbox.runtimeCaching.CacheFirst()
});
```

I get an error that runtimeCaching is undefined:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: router is not defined

So.. how do I use it and configure it in a way similar to how I could configure sw-toolbox:

```
toolbox.options.cache = {
    name: "default",
    maxEntries: 128,
    maxAgeSeconds: (60*60*24), // 24hrs
};
toolbox.router.default = toolbox.cacheFirst;
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
workboxSW.router.setDefaultHandler({
    handler: workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'default',
        cacheExpiration: {
            maxEntries: 128,
        },
        cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]},
    })
});
```

..which doesn't throw compile errors but when I use it I get this:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request method 'POST' is unsupported

..and my Cache Storage for 'default' remains empty..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my edits for Jeff's first solution were rejected I'll just go ahead and submit an answer myself.

Jeff's sample came close. He suggested:

> You could check for the request type in the default handler, and only
>   apply the cache-first strategy to GET requests:

```
workboxSW.router.setDefaultHandler({
  handler: (args) => {
    if (args.event.request.method === 'GET') {
      return workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst(args);
    }
    return fetch(args.event.request);
  },
});
```

It's the right approach but the example code he provided didn't work. The handler argument needs a handler, not a strategy. Luckily, strategies have exactly one (public) method, called "handle".

So I modified his code a little; First, I create a strategy called `defaultStrategy` with all the options I need. Then, in the setDefaultHandler call, I return `defaultStrategy.handle(args)` instead of the CacheFirst constructor. That's it!

```
// Register 'default'
var defaultStrategy = workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: "default",
    cacheExpiration: {
        maxEntries: 128,
        // more options..
    },
    cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]},
});
workboxSW.router.setDefaultHandler({
    handler: (args) => {
        if (args.event.request.method === 'GET') {
            return defaultStrategy.handle(args);
        }
        return fetch(args.event.request);
    },
});
```

**UPDATE: Workbox v3**

As I pointed out in the comments below, the above code doesn't work with Workbox v3. Use this instead:

```
// Register 'default'
var defaultStrategy = workbox.strategies.cacheFirst ({
    cacheName: "your.cache.name",
    plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 128,
            maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 1 week
            purgeOnQuotaError: true, // Opt-in to automatic cleanup
        }),
        new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
            statuses: [0, 200] // for opague requests
        }),
    ],
});
workbox.routing.setDefaultHandler(
    (args) => {
        if (args.event.request.method === 'GET') {
            return defaultStrategy.handle(args); // use default strategy
        }
        return fetch(args.event.request);
    }
);
```

Comment: Workbox 3.x broke the above code. defaultStrategy.handle is not a function :(

Comment: hey @REJH, did you find a solution?

Comment: Completely forgot to get back to this Q. Updated the above answer for v3 ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
workboxSW.router.setDefaultHandler({
  handler: workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({...})
});
```

is the right syntax in general.

I believe that you're seeing

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request method 'POST' is unsupported

because the default handler is triggered for all HTTP requests that don't match any explicit route, including HTTP `POST` requests. But a HTTP `POST` request can't be used with the Cache Storage API, and an exception similar to what you're seeing will be thrown when the cache-first strategy attempts to store the request/response pair in the cache.

In this particular case, when you know that your web app is going to make HTTP POST requests, you could take one of two approaches.

You could check for the request type in the default handler, and only apply the cache-first strategy to `GET` requests:

```
workboxSW.router.setDefaultHandler({
  handler: (args) => {
    if (args.event.request.method === 'GET') {
      return workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst(args);
    }
    return fetch(args.event.request);
  },
});
```

Alternatively, you could create a wildcard route that matches all requests, and take advantage of the fact that by default, routes will only match HTTP `GET`:

```
workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
  /./, // This should match all requests.
  workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({...}),
  'GET' // This is the default, and can be left out.
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll give your first solution a try as the 2nd will probably create duplicate cache (I have a few routes for specific url patterns, like my own app (/*/**) and a few cdns (gstatic, etc)

Comment: Hmm it looks like your first solution doesn't work. workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst takes StrategyOptions as an argument, not "args". I tried creating the strategy, putting it in a variable and returning that and now I get (for example): The FetchEvent for "https://img.youtube.com/vi/QzCyF0lrioc/0.jpg" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().

Comment: Got it working! I created the strategy and then call strategy.handle(args). I'll propose an edit for your answer :)

Comment: Seufs. My edit was rejected so I had no choice but to submit it as a new answer..